# Additional actions for cascading delete in Room

Tags: android, cascading-deletes

I have three related tables. There are Entity, Dao, and cascade delete. Everything works. But the last table stores the paths of files that also need to be deleted. Of course, you can do it with a separate code in a cycle, but it's not beautiful! Is it possible to somehow call additional actions, for example, in the Dao, which will be executed when cascading?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in `@Dao` annoted files.

You will have to do it via code. If you are using  `MVVM Architecture` , Ideal place to place this logic will be the `Repository` File

Comment: Unfortunately, the delete function from the repository is only handled when called directly, it doesn't work when cascading